# laravel 5 change app directory to match namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, directory, laravel-5

If you want to rename your app folder this is just one of several ways to go about it.

- 1) run `php artisan app:name YourNamespace`
- 2) rename your app folder to YourNamespace
- 3) in your bootstrap folder create a file called application.php
- 4) paste this in there

  ```
  class Application extends Illuminate\Foundation\Application {

      /**
       * this is the default for the application path
       */
      protected $appBasePath = 'app';

      public function __construct($basePath = null)
      {
          $this->registerBaseBindings();

          $this->registerBaseServiceProviders();

          $this->registerCoreContainerAliases();

          if ($basePath) $this->setBasePath($basePath);
      }

      public function setAppPath($path) {
          // store the path in the class only
          $this->appBasePath = $path;

          // set the path in the container (using this class's path to reset it)
          return app()->__set('path', $this->path());
      }

      /**
       * Get the path to the application "app" directory.
       *
       * @return string
       */
       public function path()
      {
          return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->appBasePath;
      }

  }
  ```
- 5) save the file and open app.php
- 6) and replace your application bootstrap with the following

  ```
   // load our local application
   require __DIR__.'/application.php';

   // instaniate our application
   $app = new \Application(
      realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
   );

   // set the path to match the namespace
   $app->setAppPath('YourNamespace');
  ```
- 7) Save your app.php and that's it, bear in mind that you should add this to your tests.

Hope this help anyone who wants to change their namespace and who wants it to match their directory structure.

Comment: Post a question then this as an answer ;)

Comment: I'm sure there was a question that inspired this write up, what was it? Otherwise I'd recommend posting this on a development blog somewhere (Stack Overflow isn't a blog though) as it's probably useful to someone.

Comment: Maybe this fits the spirit of a Community Wiki post.  I could see this being useful to someone at some point

Comment: This isn't a question at the moment. Make it an actual question, to which this post would be the answer.