# How do I change the namespace of my application in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I can't change the namespace of my application in Laravel 5.8.

I'm using artisan to change it:
**`php artisan app:name TestApp`**

Result is: There are no commands defined in the "**app**" namespace.

Comment: Hy try this  ``php artisan app:namespace TestApp``

Comment: Good explanation here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822542/laravel-5-change-app-directory-to-match-namespace

Comment: In laravel version 7 this command is deprecated. how we can achieve this goal with a command in Laravel version 7?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at `php artisan` you should have a `php artisan app:name NewNamespace`
command to change the namespace. Make sure that you are on the latest laravel version.

**Old answer**

To change the namespace of your app you have to edit the `composer.json` file:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CustomNamespace\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

but you also have to edit each file in the `app` subfolders and in the various configurations files (for example in `config/app.php`, `config/auth.php`, etc).

After you have done all of that you can run: `composer dump-autoload`

Keep in mind that this is an error prone method, because if you forget to replace a namespace in any of your files anything can stop working as expected.

---

Another option would be to create a custom package with the name you want and register it with a custom namespace. For example:

- Create a `lib/yourpackage/src` folder in the root of laravel installation
- Edit the `composer.json` file to load your custom code:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "CustomNamespace\\": "lib/yourpackage/src/",
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

- Run `composer dump-autoload` as before
- You can now use anywhere your files in your project by referring to the custom namespace you have choosen.

Comment: I see. I thought it would be as easy as the one in the Laravel docs. Thank you!

Comment: I was wrong, there is a command as @bjovanov said, I have updated my answer

Comment: I found your option for creating a custom namespace very interesting and useful. Can you edit and provide an example of how you could use that inside the code, like in a Model or in a Controller? I´m trying, but it returns me "class 'CustomNamespace' not found", when I try to import ´´´use CustomNamespace;´´´ and call inside a Model or Controller ```$someVariable = new SomeObjectInsideCustomNamespace()`;```. Is there anywhere else in Laravel I should change in order for it to work?

Comment: @JorgeMauricio I think the correct use statement should be `use CustomNamespace\SomeObjectInsideCustomNamespace;` as you have to specify the full class namespace. If not I'd suggest to open your own question to explain more in detail the problem you are facing

Answer (score 2):

laravel change this command to `app:namespace`

you have to do this

```
php artisan app:namespace TestApp
```

Comment: The command has been removed in Laravel 6

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to change the namespace of your application or just the name ?

What do you want to change exactly in the namespace ?

**EDIT**

I think you must have touched something in your application because the command `php artisan app:name AppName` should work, I just tested it.

Have you ever tried before to change the namespace by yourself?

Otherwise, try `composer dump-autoload` before to make sure your autoloading is up to date.

---

Comment: I wanted to change the default namespace of my application from App to something else.

Comment: Didn't work for me. You're right, there might be changes done in my app so app:name didn't work. app:name worked in my fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been removed as of Laravel 6. It's not recommended to change the namespace.

However if you want to do it, you can add the command to your Console/Commands directory

https://gist.github.com/isluewell/b824c0aef32f5007170fcd0d8498b657